# Webshot fails on Meteor in DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, meteor, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I am using this code to generate pdf:

```
let fileUri = process.env.PWD + '/storage/orders-pdf/' + fileName;

// Commence Webshot
webshot(html_string, fileUri, options, function(error) {
  fs.readFile(fileUri, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    fs.unlinkSync(fileUri);
    fut.return(data);
  });
});

let pdfData = fut.wait();
```

But it throws the following error:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, open '/opt/holi/storage/orders-pdf/Attributes.pdf']
   errno: 34,
   code: 'ENOENT',
   path: '/opt/holi/storage/orders-pdf/Attributes.pdf' }
```

Tried to use npm package https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot 
Then code works perfectly on localhost, but fails on the server and throws this error:

EDIT:

Even when running webshot without:

```
fs.readFile(fileUri, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

  fs.unlinkSync(fileUri);
  fut.return(data);
});
```

The file is not created..

EDIT-2:

Webshot throws an error: `[Error: PhantomJS exited with return value 2]`

EDIT-3:
Actual issue: https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot/issues/123

Comment: enoent - no such file/directory. you sure that path/file exists?

Comment: Yes! I use another function to save files to the same directory.

Comment: well, the OS doesn't usually lie ;-) can you show what you get when you run `ls -l /opt/holi/storage/orders-pdf/Attributes.pdf`?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 meteoruser root 4096 Feb  3 08:54 orders-pdf

Comment: Edited the question. If I remove fs.readFile() function - the file is not being created. But locally it works.

Comment: created? I don't get it. I only see readFile and I also see that you are deleting the file (unlink).

Comment: btw, did you check the `error` coming from webshot? maybe there was one.

Comment: ```webshot-error [Error: PhantomJS exited with return value 2] ```

Comment: maybe you didn't install phantomjs?

Comment: Shouldn't it be installed automatically as a dependancy to webshot? Just checked - and it is installed. :)

Comment: Also tried to use different versions of Phantomjs with `phantomPath`

Comment: I am struggling with this exact same issue. @R-J did you have any luck figuring it out?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and spent most of the day trying to figure out the issue. I ended up adding:

```
"phantomPath": "/usr/bin/phantomjs"
```

to my webshot options object. The phantom path I used is where mup installs phantomjs on your server setup.